# Should we Ever Change RootView Controller of IPhone Application?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to create an application.

The application will let people to read jokes, for example. Then people can press a button and another view show up where people can insert their own jokes.

After people finish inserting their own joke, I want them to go back the previous screen.

What would be the standard way to do so?

Put all controllers on application delegate and change the rootviewcontroller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The uinavigation controller will work well.  U can push people to a new controller where they enter their joke and then pop them back to the root.  U can do this with or without animation.   Set up the UiNavigationController in the app delegate and initialize  it with your jokesviewcontroller as the root.

Here is a post I just did on this subject

[Programming iOS: clarifications about Root View Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5842087/programming-ios-clarifications-about-root-view-controller/5842290#5842290)

Comment: Awesome. So rootview controllers will be the unnavigation controller and that shouldn't change.

Answer (score 2):

One possibility would be to use the `presentModalViewController:animated:` method of the root [UIViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to present the "joke inserter" view.

Once the joke insert was complete (or if the user cancelled the insertion) you'd simply return to the previous view as-is.