# Assigning a custom ViewController as the rootViewController of the window

Tags: objective-c, ios

Is this a good way to set a custom ViewController as the rootViewController of the window?

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window.rootViewController = [[[CustomViewController alloc]init] autorelease];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

In most of Apple's examples they first declare a `viewController` property, and then:

```
RootViewController* theRVC = [[RootViewController alloc] init];
self.viewController = theRVC;
[theRVC release];

[self.window addSubview:self.rvc.view];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

What is the diference between these two approaches and which is recommended?

Comment: This discussion may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5842087/programming-ios-clarifications-about-root-view-controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rootViewController property of UIWindow was recently introduced with iOS4.  This new method seems to be the recommended approach advocated by Apple.  Either approach works but I would stick with the new way of setting the rootViewController property only if you are not targeting early versions of iOS.